# Fuzzy graph automorphism group membership testing

Tags: algorithm, graph, computer-science

Suppose we're given a colored graph. Let G be its automorphism group. How do we test whether there is a permutation p in G such that p(x_i) = y_i for a given set of (x_i,y_i)? Concretely suppose that G is a permutation group over 6 elements. Then an example test that I'd like to be able to do is whether G contains any permutation that sends 2 to 2 and 3 to 5 and I don't care where 1,4,5,6 end up.

You can assume that a program like saucy can efficiently compute a set of generators for the group G.

Comment: I am rusty with group theory, but this might work: A symmetry group can be generated by transpositions (i.e., generators are permutations that only transpose adjacent elements). You can form a graph where the nodes are the elements and the edges are the the transpositions of your generating set. Then two elements are mapped to each other if there is a path between them?

Comment: For multiple mappings, maybe require the path for each one to be disjoint?

Comment: I don't think it's true that any symmetry group can be generated by transpositions. Take for example the cyclic group of 3 elements.

Comment: See http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Generators_for_Symmetric_Group for the proof. In the case of three elements, you can generate the group as: id, (12), (23), (12)(23)=(231), (23)(12)=(132), and (12)(23)(12)=(13). [(xy) means x is mapped to y and y to x; things not shown are assumed to be mapped to themselves.]

Comment: But the cyclic group of 3 elements doesn't actually contain the permutation (12), so you're generating too much. It's true that you can generate THE symmetric group with transpositions, but a graph symmetry (i.e. automorphism) group is not necessarily THE symmetric group! In fact I think that only complete graphs or graphs with no edges have S_n as their automorphism group.

Comment: Ah, I misread it as symmetry group of 3 elements. You are right, there are subgroups not generated by transpositions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If G is connected and you can run saucy on a different graph, prepare a colored graph H consisting of the disjoint union of G with itself and, for each i, recolor vertex x<sub>i</sub> in the first copy of G and y<sub>i</sub> in the second copy of G to be color i distinct from the existing colors in G. There is a suitable automorphism of G if and only if there exists a generator of Aut(H) that maps a vertex in the first copy to a vertex in the second copy.

Perhaps there is a more direct method based on [Schreier-Sims](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schreier-Sims_algorithm).

EDIT: here's one way an SS-based method could go. Let there be p pairs x<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>1</sub>, …, x<sub>p</sub>, y<sub>p</sub>. If p = 0, the answer is of course *yes*. Otherwise, determine whether there exists a permutation g that carries x<sub>p</sub> to y<sub>p</sub>, i.e., x<sub>p</sub><sup>g</sup> = y<sub>p</sub>. If not so, the answer is *no*. If so, the permutation you're looking for exists if and only if it can be written in the form h g (g followed by h), where h belongs to the stabilizer of y<sub>p</sub>. Use the SS machinery to compute generators for the stabilizer and return the answer computed recursively for x<sub>1</sub><sup>g</sup>, y<sub>1</sub>, …, x<sub>p-1</sub><sup>g</sup>, y<sub>p-1</sub>.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have any idea what kind of methods or objects you have defined, but in pseudo code you're looking at something like:

```
foreach (permutation p in G) {
    if p.permute(2) == 2 && p.permute(3) == 5:
         return true
}
return false
```

assuming that p is an object that has a permute method.

Comment: Right, that's what I want to achieve. I forgot to mention efficiency ;) This brute force algorithm actually takes O(n!) time not even including the cost of enumerating the elements of the automorphism group. Since my graphs can have 1000+ vertices this is not practical.

Comment: How are you storing the permutations? It shouldn't be too awfully expensive if you're storing them as associative arrays or something -- p.permute(2) should be like calling p[2] in a hashmap which is very fast.

Comment: I'm not storing the permutations. The group is implicitly represented as the automorphism group of a colored graph. Since these graphs can have a very high number of symmetries the group G can be very large (like 100! elements).

Comment: I think you're gonna have to use math for this one, not software optimization.

Comment: I agree, just optimizing the brute force algorithm doesn't cut it; a different algorithm is needed.

Comment: I think what you need is some results from group theory. Some way to deduce from the graph graph itself whether or not there exists such an automorphism. I don't remember hardly any group theory, but youd basically be trying to figure out if there's some sort of appropriate relation on, in your example, the set {2}, and the set {3, 5} that guarantees the existence of an automorphism wit that property, right?

Comment: Right, well, part has been solved already. Computing the automorphism group is actually not known to be possible in polynomial time because it is strictly harder than the graph isomorphism problem. However there are algorithms that handle large graphs efficiently in practice, like saucy. So you actually don't have to look at the graph (though you can if that helps) but you can just use the set of generators of G that saucy outputs. So this makes it possible to ignore the graph entirely and just focus on the problem of finding a partial permutation of a group represented by its generators.